# ¿Es correcto utilizar la palabra "desencriptar"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, verbos, definiciones, vocabulario-técnico, informática

Mi duda surge a partir de que la palabra *[encriptar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=FABu3oz)* es sinónimo de la palabra *[cifrar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9Blo7Je)*, para lo cual su acción contraria sería *[descifrar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Ceu04o5)*. Entonces, ¿cuál es el término opuesto de ***encriptar***?

De acuerdo a la RAE, no existe el término *desencriptar* y no estoy seguro que sea correcto utilizarlo.

Comment: Muy similar: [How do you say “Choose file to encrypt” and “Choose file to decrypt” in Spanish?](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/19523/12637)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Que una palabra no venga en el diccionario no quiere decir que no exista. Este probablemente sea uno de esos casos de palabra compuesta con significado transparente. Sabemos que *encriptar* viene en el diccionario, lo único que habría que ver es qué significa el prefijo *des-*:

> **[des-](http://dle.rae.es/?id=CJuPwUn)**
>
> 1. pref. Denota negación o inversión del significado de la palabra simple a la que va antepuesto. *Desconfiar, deshacer.*

Así pues, si *encriptar* significa *cifrar*, *desencriptar* denota el paso inverso a *cifrar*, que sería *descifrar*. Por motivos de ahorro, si una palabra no tiene ningún significado más allá de la suma de sus componentes, no suele aparecer en el diccionario.

Curiosamente, no encuentro ningún caso en el CREA, pero buscando artículos periodísticos aparecen textos [como este](http://hemeroteca.abc.es/nav/Navigate.exe/hemeroteca/madrid/abc/2002/01/05/023.html) del diario ABC del 5 de enero de 2002:

> Especialistas del FBI trabajan en España en colaboración con la Policía para desencriptar los ordenadores intervenidos a ETA [...].

Comment: ¡Excelente respuesta! Muchas gracias por la información :D Ahora me queda una duda, tanto tu respuesta como la @fedorqui me han cambiado totalmente el panorama, no sabría cuál de las dos marcar como la mejor :D

Comment: @Flxtr un placer. Sobre lo de aceptar una respuesta, simplemente acepta la que te haya resultado más útil para resolver tu duda. :)

Answer (score 5):

Estoy de acuerdo con lo que explica Carlos Alejo en [su respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20047/1674).  Efectivamente, lo permitido y lo incluido en el RAE no es una biyección, por lo que hay cosas permitidas que no están en la RAE.

Adicionalmente, quería indicar que el [IATE](http://iate.europa.eu/SearchByQueryLoad.do?method=load) (Base de datos terminológica multilingüe de la Unión Europea) sugiere las siguientes traducciones para *decrypt*:

> [Information technology and data processing [COM]](http://iate.europa.eu/SearchByQuery.do?method=searchDetail&lilId=1399394&langId=&query=decrypt&sourceLanguage=en&domain=0&matching=&start=0&next=1&targetLanguages=es)
>
> inglés: decrypt / decipher
>   castellano: descifrar
>
> [Information technology and data processing [EP]](http://iate.europa.eu/SearchByQuery.do?method=searchDetail&lilId=204002&langId=&query=decrypt&sourceLanguage=en&domain=0&matching=&start=0&next=1&targetLanguages=es)
>
> inglés: decrypt / decipher
>   castellano: descifrar / decodificar

Los enlaces de los títulos llevan a la ficha completa.

Por tanto, parece que tanto **descifrar** que tú comentas como **decodificar** podrían ser opciones válidas. Nótese que las fichas indican "Reliability not verified", por lo que sería algo escéptico en cuanto a su uso. Debo reconocer que yo siempro uso *desencriptar*.

Comment: Como siempre, excelente información @fedorqui aunque me parece que los enlaces están rotos :( Aún así, al igual que Carlos me han dejado algo muy claro, que no esté en la RAE no significa que sea incorrecto. ¡Gracias por la información!, será de gran utilizadad para mis dudas e investigaciones a futuro :D

Comment: @Flxtr caramba, tienes razón: los enlaces solo funcionan cuando tienes la sesión abierta tras hacer la búsqueda.

Answer (score 0):

Desencriptar y descifrar computacionalmente no son lo mismo, por eso en inglés tienen dos términos distintos. Utilizar en castellano el termino descifrar para ambas cosas a mi me parece un error.

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a [Spanish.SE]! Si crees que los términos no son intercambiables, te animamos a que expliques cuál es la diferencia y nos pongas ejemplos de uso. En todo caso, no debemos perder el foco de la pregunta, que simplemente pedía saber si el término _desencriptar_ es correcto en español. Si tu intención era hacer un comentario a otra respuesta, te sugerimos que ganes un poco de experiencia en el sitio: con 50 puntos de karma (5 votos positivos) ya podrás dejar comentarios en cualquier parte.

Comment: Tal y como explica @Carlos, la respuesta es interesante pero requiere de algo más de chicha para que sea de utilidad. Échale una ojeada a [answer] tras pasearte por el [tour]. Después, dale a [edit] para mejorar la publicación. ¡Gracias!

Comment: Además, recuerda que el hecho de que una lengua tiene dos términos distintos para referir a dos conceptos distintos no significa que otra tenga que hacer la misma distinción con dos palabras.

Comment: @Charlie Lo que creo que Paco intentó decir es que descifrar tiene una connotación de "desconocimiento de la forma de volver al mensaje original, por lo que se deben probar métodos (y errar) para finalmente obtener la información" en cambio desencriptar tedría una de "aplicar un trabajo (conocido) sobre un texto encriptado para obtener la información en él".

Answer (score 0):

Estoy de acuerdo con @Paco, computacionalmente es obtener texto claro de un texto cifrado, pero con diferencias, como apunta @EmmanuelMess.

- 'decrypt' (desencriptar) es el descifrado de un texto **sin el conocimiento de la clave**.

Mientras que

- 'decipher' (descifrar) es la conversión de información cifrada en texto claro mediante un sistema criptográfico, **conociendo la clave**.